# Pandas - How to calculate for each group ,for each value in a column what percentage of value is equal and less than that

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Lets say I  have a dataframe like this

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'person':['a','b']*5 , 'rating':[1,3,4,2,4,2,3,4,5,3]})
```

Now I want to calculate for each person ,each rating's 'preference score' .
Now I define preference score for rating r as

```
freq of rating where rating <=r  -  freq of rating where rating ==r
```

For example a has the following rating

```
0   a   1
2   a   4
4   a   4
6   a   3
8   a   5
```

now for example  rating =4  for person `a`

```
freq of rating where rating <=4  :  4/5 
freq of rating where rating ==4   : 2/5
```

so the preference score is 2/5

How do I do achieve the preference score for each record on that data frame .
EDIT :Perhaps this makes it more clear

```
   person rating    pref_score
        a   1       0.0
        a   4       0.4
        a   4       0.4
        a   3       0.2
        a   5       0.8
```

Comment: will the downvoter  pls explain why he/she downvoted .  .

Comment: Likely because no attempt at a solution was made.

Comment: freq of rating where rating <=r  -  freq of rating where rating==freq of rating where rating <r

Answer (score 2):

so you need something like this ?

```
x.groupby('person').rating.apply(lambda x : (sum(x<=4)-sum(x==4))/len(x))
Out[7]: 
person
a    0.4
b    0.8
Name: rating, dtype: float64
```

Or `transform` ?

```
x.groupby('person').rating.transform(lambda x : (sum(x<=4)-sum(x==4))/len(x))
Out[8]: 
0    0.4
1    0.8
2    0.4
3    0.8
4    0.4
5    0.8
6    0.4
7    0.8
8    0.4
9    0.8
Name: rating, dtype: float64
```

EDIT :

```
x=x.sort_values('person')
x['ref']=x.groupby('person').rating.apply(lambda y : [(sum(y<=x)-sum(y==x))/len(y) for x in y]).apply(pd.Series).stack().values
x
Out[25]: 
  person  rating  ref
0      a       1  0.0
2      a       4  0.4
4      a       4  0.4
6      a       3  0.2
8      a       5  0.8
1      b       3  0.4
3      b       2  0.0
5      b       2  0.0
7      b       4  0.8
9      b       3  0.4
```

Since you are using python 2.7

```
x['map']=x.person.map(x.groupby('person').rating.apply(list))
x.apply(lambda x : sum(x['rating']<np.array(x['map']))/len(x['map']),1 )
```

Comment: How do I generalize that to the whole data frame , I have used  that  as an example .

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted .Thanks

Comment: @Bg1850 yw :-)  happy coding

Comment: Hi when I tried this ,I get all the ref as zero . could this be a python version issue ,I am using python 2.7

Comment: @Bg1850 I am using python 3.5 and pandas 0.20

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
>> x.groupby("person").rating.apply(lambda x: x[x <= 4].count())
person
a    4
b    5
```

and

```
>> x.groupby("person").rating.apply(lambda x: x[x == 4].count())
person
a    2
b    1
```

Comment: You want this: `x.groupby("person").rating.apply(lambda x: x[x <= 4].count() - x[x == 4].count())`?

Comment: @Bg1850 just saying "re-read my question" doesn't help make better answers, please give more specific feedback about why this doesn't answer your question or how it can be improved.

Comment: Sorry for that comment ,but I thought I clearly explained what I meant . For each rating in each group I want a preference score , I explained with an example what do I mean by the preference score for person a's rating 4 .

Comment: So for the result, you want something like a matrix with users in rows and each rating in columns?

Comment: How do I do achieve the preference score for each record on that data frame .
I have used a's rating 4 as an example to show what I meant , I want this to be generalized to a whole data frame .